# Commutation relations for a CFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

**Exercise**

To calculate the commutator $[L_m ; \phi_n]$ where:

$$T(z) = \sum \frac{L_m}{z^{m+2}} \hspace{5mm} and \hspace{5mm} \phi(w) = \sum \phi_n \frac{1}{w^{n+h}} \tag{1}$$

using contour integrals and where the OPE for a primary field of weight $h$ with the energy-momentum tensor is

$$T(z)\phi(w) \sim \frac{h\phi w }{(z-w)^2} + \frac{\partial \phi(w)}{z-w}+ ... \tag{2}$$

**My take on it**

My first instinct was to commutate $L_m$ and $\phi_n$, meaning $[L_m ; \phi_n]= L_m\phi_n-\phi_nL_m$

We write the following modes where the contour circles the origin  $$L_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i } \oint dz \hspace{1mm}z^{n+1}T(z) \tag{3}$$

and

$$\phi_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint \phi(w) w^{n+h-1} \tag{4}$$

**Problem**

But when comparing this to my lecturer's notes he gets:

$$[L_m ; \phi_n] = \frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint \phi(w) w^{n+h-1} \frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint_w \phi(w) w^{n+h-1} \tag{5}$$

later the OPE is substituted in :

$$[L_m ; \phi_n] = \frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint dw\frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint dz \left(\frac{h\phi w}{(z-w)^2} +\frac{\partial \phi }{(z-w)}\right) z^{m+1}w^{n+h-1}$$

The regular terms do not contribute to the integral. Integrating by parts in z in the first term, we get:

$$[L_m ; \phi_n] = \frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint dw\frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint dz \left(\frac{h\phi w}{(z-w)}(m+1)z^m +\frac{\partial \phi }{(z-w)}\right)$$

**This doesn't make sense to me as it looks like a multiplication  of the two terms, $L_n$ and $\phi_n$ instead of a commutation relation. Why is is this correct?**

**I understand that adding a second term would probably just cancel out with the first one, but shouldn't there be a second one, as it is a commutation?**

**Why is the first term the only one integrated by parts in z, why is the latter term not takeninto consideration?**

Comment: Fig 2.4(a) in Polchinski and the discussion surrounding it is very clean and instructive.

Comment: You need to pay attention to the contours being integrated over, this question is effectively unanswerable because e.g. the correctness of eq. (5) depends very much on the contours chosen, but you haven't defined any of the contours here.

Comment: I have found two different sets of polchinski notes, but none with a 2.4 fig, have you got a link? Thank you

Comment: @gfgc - I mean his book (String Theory Volume 1, page 54,55).